# Hide Button in CustomPagerAdapter

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, visibility

I wrote the following custom `ViewPager` adapter:

```
public class CustomPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

private int[] image_resources = {
        android.R.color.transparent,
        R.drawable.1,
        R.drawable.2,
};
private Context ctx;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
public CustomPagerAdapter(Context ctx) {
    this.ctx = ctx;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return image_resources.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object o) {
    return (view == (RelativeLayout) o);
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    String[] titlesArray = {
            "",
            "Image 1",
            "Image 2",
    };

    return titlesArray[position];
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View item_view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.pager_item, container, false);
    ImageView imageview = (ImageView) item_view.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
    imageview.setImageResource(image_resources[position]);
    container.addView(item_view);
    return item_view;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    container.removeView((RelativeLayout) object);
}
}
```

I set up the `Adapter` in another class:

```
private void init(Context context) {
    View view = inflate(context, R.layout.listview_item, this);
    view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    ViewPager viewPager;
    CustomPagerAdapter adapter;
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    adapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(context);

    PagerAdapter wrappedAdapter = new InfinitePagerAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.setAdapter(wrappedAdapter);

    //Hide the button unless showing image
    Button selectButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.selectButton);
    selectButton .setVisibility(GONE);
}
```

How would I hide the button on the first "slide" of the `ViewPager`, i.e. where the image is `android.R.color.transparent`, but show it for every other slide?

Comment: Is your button part of R.layout.pager_item? If yes then you can hide it with if condition. `if(position=0)` then hide.

Comment: No, unfortunately the button is defined in an xml file associated with the class where init() is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't fully understand your question but I believe this should solve your problem:

```
private void init(Context context) {
    View view = inflate(context, R.layout.listview_item, this);
    view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    ViewPager viewPager;
    CustomPagerAdapter adapter;
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    adapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(context);

    PagerAdapter wrappedAdapter = new InfinitePagerAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.setAdapter(wrappedAdapter);

    //Hide the button unless showing image
    final Button selectButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.selectButton);
    selectButton .setVisibility(GONE);

    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
             if(position==0)
                selectButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
             else
                selectButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });


}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use onPageChangeListener on your pager like this and hide the button by checking the position of pager's current page.

```
    pager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

           if(position == position of the page you want to hide button)
            {
                button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }else{
                 button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add an [`OnPageChangeListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html) to the `ViewPager` to get notified of page changes. In its most basic form, toggling the visibility of your button based on the current page would look somewhat like this:

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        selectButton.setVisibility(position == 0 ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
    }
});
```

Note: I've used the [`SimpleOnPageChangeListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener.html) in order to only have to override what I'm interested in.